# How to check if shell is in tty?

Tags: linux, bash, tty

### Motivation

I would like to set the `$EDITOR` variable depending on if I'm in the tty at the moment or not. Something like this would be nice:

```sh
if [[ <is in tty> ]]; then
    export EDITOR=nvim
else
    export EDITOR=neovide
fi
```

I want this if-branch, because [`neovide`](https://github.com/neovide/neovide) is a GUI frontend for neovim and if I'm in the tty then of course I won't be able to open it, so I'd like to have `nvim` as my default `$EDITOR` if I'm in the tty.

### Question (TL;DR)

As the title says: How can I check if the my shell has been loaded in a tty or in a terminal?

Comment: `if [ -t 0 ]; then` -- this is almost certainly duplicative.

Comment: "this is almost certainly duplicative" what do you mean with this? Could you also please explain me what `-t 0` does or a link where I can read it up?

Comment: Try running `tty` in both environments and see the different ouput.

Comment: You seem to be asking a wrong question. If you want to know if you can run a GUI program, you should be asking whether GUI is available, not anything about the tty.

Comment: `-t   True if file descriptor fd is open and refers to a terminal.` See [man 1 bash - heading: CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) And `stdin` is `fd == 0` (file number `0`, `stdout` is `1` and `stderr` is `2`)

Comment: As the above says -- whether you have a TTY and whether you can run GUI apps are two completely different questions. For the latter we'd need to know which operating system you run, and with which GUI framework (if it supports more than one, as with Linux supporting both X and Wayland).

Comment: BTW, traditionally there are two different variables, EDITOR and VISUAL, to specify preferred GUI-based and text-only editors.